# PHP Imagick Images getting truncated on download, but only some of the time

Tags: php, image-processing, download, imagick

When I am using PHP Imagick() to resize and offer up an image for download, the resulting image is often truncated.

I can't diagnose when this happens, but it happens enough that it is a problem.  In this code, $file is a much larger image file of which I want to order a smaller download.

```
    if (file_exists($file)) {

    $image = new Imagick();
    $image->setResolution(150,150);
    $image->readImage($file);
    $image->resizeImage(1275,0,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1);
    $image->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=download.'.$extension);
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    echo $image;
    exit;

    }
```

What's happening is, some of the time the files download correctly, and sometimes the image is truncated--only the top 30% of the image looks right and the rest is just blank.  So the file dimensions are correct but the image data only makes it halfway.

What might be causing the problem--but still doesn't happen consistently--is that I am doing this with PDFs, JPEGs and PNGs alike, and outputting them as whatever their original extensions were.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:  Figured it out, see below.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot---turns out I was taking 'Content-Length' of the $file, not the $image.  I just changed $file to $image and it works fine.  Content-Length needs to be correct or it will truncate!

Nevermind!